# Does having my garbage collection keep pyside/Qt references to sub-widgets as member variables prevent proper cleanup?

Tags: python, qt, garbage-collection, pyside

Here is what I have, from a garbage-collection/proper cleanup perspective:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,qtParent):
        QWidget.__init__(self,qtParent):
        
        self.mySubWidget = MySubWidget(self)  # <-- keeping a direct reference to the child
```

When I destroy MyWidget, will mySubWidget also get correctly destroyed by Qt/pyside/python when I call the code below?

```
setAttribute( Qt.DeleteOnClose, True)
myWidget.close()
```

Or, should I use weakrefs like below?

```
import weakref

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,qtParent):
        QWidget.__init__(self,qtParent):
        
        self.mySubWidget = weakref.ref(MySubWidget(self))
```

Comment: If you're in doubt about when an object is freed, give it a [`__del__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) and find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is fine. If you don't have any other reference to the created `MySubWidget` outside of your instance, then it will be garbage collected when you delete the `MyWidget` instance.